# How to add a form to $node in hook_node_load()?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I want to add a form to a node before it is passed along to the theme layer.

My module has a [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7), as follows:

```
function gp_shop_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach($nodes as $nid => $node) {
    //Determine if we should process. aka: only run on Record->type() types.
    if (!in_array("product", $types)) {
      continue;
    }

    $nodes[$nid]->gp_shop_order_button = "[BUTTON]";
  }
}
```

This works: the text *[BUTTON]* is added to $node if it is type "product";

However, when placing an actual form, it breaks in a `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`-error. An endless loop of some sorts. As follows:

```
    $nodes[$nid]->gp_shop_order_button = drupal_get_form("gp_shop_order_button", $node);
```

Edit: In the final code, I problably have to wrap this in a `drupal_render()` even; for now it makes no difference. The relevant line would then be:

```
$nodes[$nid]->gp_shop_order_button = drupal_render(drupal_get_form("gp_shop_order_button", $product));
```

And then with the callback-hook for the form.

```
function gp_shop_order_button($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  $form = array();

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Order',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

The part about passing along the $nodeis not very relevant and is not causing the problem. Just left it in my examples here, to illustrate that passing along parameters *is* a requirement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stab in the dark...the constructor for your `Product` class calls `node_load` internally, causing an infinite loop

Comment: No. The class has nothing to do with this. I removed it entirely and the recursion still occurs. I'll update my code to make the example and problem more clear. Sec.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure why `hook_node_load` does not work, but some trial and error (in contrast to the documentation) led me to a working solution using `hook_node_view` instead.

The example code being:

```
function gp_shop_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ("product" == $node->type) {
    if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node)) {
      $node->content['gp_shop_order_button'] = drupal_get_form("gp_shop_order_button", $node);
      }
    }
  }
}

function gp_shop_order_button($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  $form = array();

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Order',
  );

  return $form;
}
```